# Unable to access sqlserver driver from dbt

Tags: sql-server, pip, homebrew, dbt

I have previously setup dbt in my mac (Ventura 13.3) for postgres & redshift by using `brew` commands in different project.

```
brew update
brew install git
brew tap dbt-labs/dbt
brew install dbt-postgres
brew install dbt-redshift
```

and now I need to setup dbt for mssql in a new project by using the following commands as recommended by [dbt website](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-setups/mssql-setup):

```
    brew update
    brew install git
    brew tap dbt-labs/dbt
    python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
    python3 -m pip install dbt-sqlserver==1.3.1
```

I then configured my profile as below:

```
mssql:
  outputs:
    dev:
      dbname: mssql
      host: host_name
      password: pwd
      port: 2433
      schema: dbo
      threads: 1
      type: sqlserver
      user: sql_user
      driver: 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' 
      trust_cert: true
  target: dev
```

When I tried to compile and I was hit with error below:

```
07:13:06  Error importing adapter: No module named 'dbt.adapters.sqlserver'
07:13:06  Encountered an error while reading profiles:
  ERROR: Runtime Error
  Credentials in profile "mssql", target "dev" invalid: Runtime Error
    Could not find adapter type sqlserver!Defined profiles:
 - mssql
For more information on configuring profiles, please consult the dbt docs:

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configure-your-profile

07:13:06  Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
  Could not run dbt
```

I checked my dbt version by running `dbt --version` and received logs below:

```
Core:
  - installed: 1.4.5
  - latest:    1.5.0 - Update available!

  Your version of dbt-core is out of date!
  You can find instructions for upgrading here:
  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/installation

Plugins:
  - redshift: 1.4.0 - Update available!
  - postgres: 1.4.5 - Update available!

  At least one plugin is out of date or incompatible with dbt-core.
  You can find instructions for upgrading here:
  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/installation
```

It appears that dbt is not picking up the mssql package installed as a plugin.
Could someone advise what I did wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you realize that port 5439 is the default port for a Postgres server? Is your SQL Server really listening on that port? (The default `MSSQLSERVER` instance typically listens on port 1433.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The default port for a Postgres server is [5432](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @AlwaysLearning. That's a redshift port. Updating to the mssql port doesn't fix the issue unfortunately. From the error message, it appears that dbt is unable to find the mssql package.